# Deploying Ruby ond Rails app at 1&1 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

I am currently developing a `ruby on rails` application and have a 1&1 webspace now for several years. My question, is there any opportunity to deploy this app at 1&1? Would be cool if I don't need another hoster like AWS or heroku to deploy it. I can not find any information about that.

greetz

Comment: Depends on the type of your hosting package. Do you have root access? Can you install new software?

Comment: I have the 1&1 dual unlimited package. It says that I can run ruby, but I have no clue how to set this up :/

Comment: Maybe contact their support?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about 1&1, but let me tell you this about Rails hosting:

**Rails**

Rails is not just another web scripting system - it requires a lot of dependencies to be installed on the server

The problem for many hosts is to handle all of these dependencies in their current environment. Lots of shared hosting is set up to provide `Xgb` of space & hosting of MYSQL & PHP, all of which just run

Rails has its own compilation & deployment process, uses the [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) system, and is basically a lot more intensive than your typical website. Because of this, you need an environment which supports it properly, hence the popularity of Heroku & AWS

---

**Services**

We used [Site5](http://site5.com) for years, and when the time came to create RoR apps, they were lacking

We moved to Heroku & AWS because it supports rails by default. All the latest gems & dependencies work out of the box & the deployment process is simple

Instead of looking at whether 1&1 provide support for RoR, I'd look at which hosting provider is going to provide the best environment to make your RoR apps run successfully

Comment: thx for the hint. I guess I'll give heroku a try then. ;) Just better for the starting phase. When getting more traffic I'll probably switch to aws.

Comment: Heroku is actually just a software front for AWS (it runs on their servers). You pay Heroku, who will then pay their AWS fee with that :) So either way, you're hosting with Amazon. Heroku is very powerful, but slightly restricted, as you surmised. A "naked" AWS instance is probably best for apps which need to scale